# How to add an ICustomFormatter to the default formatters?

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting

The `string.Format` method supports several default formattings and allows you to specify a custom format provider if necessary.

But is there a way to register an `ICustomFormatter` so that it is automatically picked without using the overload and specifying it explicitly?

```
string.Format("foo {0:bar} baz", "qux");
```

I'd like the `Format` be able to find the `barFormatter`

```
class barFormatter : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter {}
```

without having to write:

```
string.Format(new barFormatter(), "foo {0:bar} baz", "qux");
```

EDIT:

This is the closest I came up with so far:

```
public class ExtendableFormatter : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    public IDictionary<Type, IFormatProvider> FormatProviders { get; set; }

    public ExtendableFormatter()
    {
        FormatProviders = new Dictionary<Type, IFormatProvider>
        {
            { typeof(Byte), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat },
            { typeof(SByte), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat },
            { typeof(Int16), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat },
            { typeof(Int32), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat },
            { typeof(Int64), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat },
            { typeof(UInt16), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat },
            { typeof(UInt32), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat },
            { typeof(UInt64), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat },
            { typeof(Single), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat },
            { typeof(Double), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat },
            { typeof(Decimal), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat },
            { typeof(DateTime), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat },
            { typeof(String), new StringCaseFormatter() }
        };
    }

    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        return formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter) ? this : null;
    }

    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        var fp = (IFormatProvider)null;
        if (FormatProviders.TryGetValue(arg.GetType(), out fp))
        {
            formatProvider = fp;
        }

        format = string.IsNullOrEmpty(format) ? string.Empty : ":" + format;
        var result = string.Format(formatProvider, "{0" + format + "}", arg);
        return result;
    }

}

public class StringCaseFormatter : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        return formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter) ? this : null;
    }

    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        switch (format)
        {
            case "U": return arg.ToString().ToUpper();
            case "L": return arg.ToString().ToLower();
            default: return arg.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
string.Format(
    new ExtendableFormatter(),
    "foo {0:U} baz {1,-5:f1} {2:ddMMMyy}",
    "qux", 1.234f, DateTime.Now).Dump();
```

Result:

> foo QUX baz 1.2   05Jun16

I'm guessing there is no other way to solve it but using a custom formatter like this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by implementing a composite formatter. The complete code can be found o Code Review under [Custom string formatters](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138747/custom-string-formatters).

Comment: I'm seeing your code and can't understand how does it work?

Comment: @wishmaster35 maybe the code in my repo on [GitHub](https://github.com/he-dev/Reusable/tree/master/Reusable.Converters/TehCodez) helps you more. Basically the `TypeConverter` is an immutable type that is at the same time a collection of other type-converters. For more examples see the [test project](https://github.com/he-dev/Reusable/tree/master/Reusable.Converters.Tests)

Comment: @t3chb0t dead repo

Comment: @Adaptabi here's the [current branch](https://github.com/he-dev/reusable/tree/dev/Reusable.OneTo1)